# jQuery Wildcare Image Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wildcard

I am trying to change a part of an image src for an A/B test but after reading tons of articles I am getting more and more confused. This is the image URL (it is part of a resultlist-item):

http://pic.test.net/images-small/001/002/123456.jpg

and I have to change /image-small/ to /image-big/.

Parts of the URL are dynamic (e.g. /001/) so my idea was to use some kind of wildcard for those parts. This is my version for a static URL:

```
$("#resultlist-item").attr({"src":"http://pic.test.net/images-big/001/002/123456.jpg"});
```

It is working but I have no idea how to do it for a dynamic URL.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Joe

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic url?

Comment: @Satpal Basically the image is part of an ad and I get the details via an API. So the numbers in the image url may vary but the first part 
"http://pic.test.net/images-small" is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!-- SOME HTML AND ETC... -->   
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://pic.test.net/images-small/001/002/123456.jpg" />
    <img src="http://pic.test.net/images-small/001/002/1234567.jpg" />
    <img src="http://pic.test.net/images-small/001/002/1234568.jpg" />
</div>
<!-- SOME HTML AND ETC... --> 

<script>
$(function(){
    var $imagesContainer = $('#gallery');
    $imagesContainer.find('img').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if(src.indexOf('images-small/')>-1) {
            src = src.replace('images-small/', 'images-big/');
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```